# php How to send user email to activate their account

Tags: php, email, handshake

I'm doing a simple login page. Want to confirm the user account by sending them a link in their email when they sign up. So when they click on it, their account is activated. How do i do this?  Only have a basic form.

- First Name:
- Last Name:
- Email:

...etc

Comment: see mail() function...

Answer (score 1):

You want a boolean field in your database called "activated" or something. When the user signs up, make it false. Then use the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send an email with a link to an activation page. Something like www.example.com/activate.php?user_id=123

In that page you just want to find the user with that id, ask them to confirm their password and update the "activated" field to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a kind of a hashed ID to identify the user. Put that ID into the verification URL instead of the user id to allowed only the "real" user to verification historischen account/email address.

Example: .../verify/g5jd31zcxh7kob